# SPARQL When do we use the "a"

Tags: sparql, jena

I'm new on SPARQL. I read the tutorial on Jena (https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/sparql.html) and I understand most of the example. But I don't really understand when we have to use the `a`

For example with this triples :

```
@prefix vCard:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<http://somewhere/MattJones/>  vCard:FN   "Matt Jones" .
<http://somewhere/MattJones/>  vCard:N    _:b0 .
_:b0  vCard:Family "Jones" .
_:b0  vCard:Given  "Matthew" .


<http://somewhere/RebeccaSmith/> vCard:FN    "Becky Smith" .
<http://somewhere/RebeccaSmith/> vCard:N     _:b1 .
_:b1 vCard:Family "Smith" .
_:b1 vCard:Given  "Rebecca" .

<http://somewhere/JohnSmith/>    vCard:FN    "John Smith" .
<http://somewhere/JohnSmith/>    vCard:N     _:b2 .
_:b2 vCard:Family "Smith" .
_:b2 vCard:Given  "John"  .

<http://somewhere/SarahJones/>   vCard:FN    "Sarah Jones" .
<http://somewhere/SarahJones/>   vCard:N     _:b3 .
_:b3 vCard:Family  "Jones" .
_:b3 vCard:Given   "Sarah" .
```

We can write something like this :

```
PREFIX vcard:      <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#>

SELECT ?y ?givenName
WHERE
 { ?y vcard:Family "Smith" .
   ?y vcard:Given  ?givenName .
 }
```

But I the slideshow of my course I found something like this :

```
SELECT ?label_du_président ?âge_du_président ? label_du_pays
WHERE {
    ?une_élection a ex:electionPrésidentielle .
    ?une_élection ex:gagnéePar ?un_president .
    ?une_élection ex:alieuDans ?un_pays .
    ?un_president rdfs:label ?label_du_president .
    ?un_president ex:âge ?âge_du_president .
    ?un_pays rdfs:label ?label_du_pays
}
```

Why and when use the `a` ?

Comment: I urge you to use [`http://example/` and related](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606) instead of `http://somewhere/` which may someday resolve and thus lead to trouble down the line.

Comment: That was the paste of the Jena doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a shorthand notation for the `rdf:type` property. From the [SPARQL Query Language specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#abbrevRdfType):

> The keyword "a" can be used as a predicate in a triple pattern and is an alternative for the IRI  http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type. This keyword is case-sensitive.

Think of it as meaning "is a (kind of)".

Comment: Thank you so much !
So in my example it's used to say "I want in ?une_election only kind of ex:electionPresidentielle ?